# create dictionary from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a dictionary with two lists using map function. But something doesn't seem right.

I know there is already zip and dict to do this job, but I am wondering why this code went wrong and where.

```
country = ['India', 'Pakistan', 'Nepal', 'Bhutan', 'China', 'Bangladesh']
capital = ['New Delhi', 'Islamabad','Kathmandu', 'Thimphu', 'Beijing', 
'Dhaka']

country_capital={}

def mydict(x,y):
  country_capital[x]=y
  return country_capital
national_info=map(mydict,country,capital)
print (list(national_info))
```

why it prints as below:

`[{'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 
'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}]`

I wanted like this:

`[{'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}]`

Comment: Do you have to make it so complicated? `dict(zip(country, capital))` does exactly what you want. `map` does not do what you want it to: it applies it for every item in a list, and modifies a global for no reason. There's so many things you just don't want to do: use builtins, or make simple-reusable tools so messes like this don't occur.

Comment: just print `list(country_capital)` instead of `national_info`. The output of map is a list with all the return values of your function (list of n pointers to `country_capital` in your case)

Comment: @AndreyF you should post this as an answer since this actually is the only __correct__ answer (the one answering the question instead of proposing another solution).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers just did

Answer (score 2):

`dict` accepts an iterable of two-element iterables, so all you need to issue is

```
country_capital = dict(zip(country, capital))
```

(For some reason, your expected result wraps this dictionary in a one-element list. I don't see any reason to do this.)

Answer (score 2):

People here suggested much cleaner way to solve your problem (a way you are aware of as mentioned in your question).

Regarding your question:

> why it prints as below:

```
[{'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}, {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 
'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}]
```

The `map` method applies your function on each element of your lists and collect the return values to a new list.

Your function returns the global variable `country_capital` to which you add elements. Therefore the output of your `map` (`national_info`) is a list with `n` pointers to  `country_capital`.

If you'll print `country_capital` instead of `national_info` you'll get the output you want.

Comment: Pfeww, at least someone made the effort to actually __read__ the question and answer it instead of posting alternate solutions (that the OP explicitely mentionned he was aware of).

Answer (score 0):

```
country = ['India', 'Pakistan', 'Nepal', 'Bhutan', 'China', 'Bangladesh']
capital = ['New Delhi', 'Islamabad','Kathmandu', 'Thimphu', 'Beijing', 'Dhaka']


d = dict(zip(country, capital )) #{i:v for i, v in zip(country, capital )}
print d
```

**Result**:

```
{'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'India': 'New Delhi', 'China': 'Beijing'}
```

Comment: More idiomatic: `dict(zip(country, capital))`. `dict` takes a constructor from an iterable of 2-item tuples. No list comprehension needed.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh. Thanks :)

Comment: @Rakesh Your second solution still doesn't work. You could make a function that creates a tuple (basically like a limited version of `zip`, as RoadRunner does below), which will work, but your second answer creates a list of dicts with a single key per dict. You want to return `(x, y)`, not `{x: y}`, from `mydict`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `map()` tuples of `(country, capital)`, then wrap `dict` to get the final dictionary:

```
>>> country = ['India', 'Pakistan', 'Nepal', 'Bhutan', 'China', 'Bangladesh']
>>> capital = ['New Delhi', 'Islamabad','Kathmandu', 'Thimphu', 'Beijing', 'Dhaka']
>>> dict(map(lambda x, y: (x, y), country, capital))
  {'India': 'New Delhi', 'Pakistan': 'Islamabad', 'Nepal': 'Kathmandu', 'Bhutan': 'Thimphu', 'China': 'Beijing', 'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'}
```

Comment: did you bother READING the question ??? "I know there is already zip and dict to do this job, but I am wondering why this code went wrong and where."

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with posting an alternate solution to the problem. The OP and future readers benefit both ways from having a variety of answers. You also sound pretty rude in your spammed comments across this question, not a good way to make friends on this site.

Comment: There's no problem with posting an alternate solution if and when you (or someone else) first answer the actual question,  specially when the op did _explicitely_ mention he was aware of the alternative solutions. And I don't care about "making friends" here actually.

Answer (score 0):

All the given answers will get you the results you need. However, you can never get the results you need with the code you wrote.
The resultant output list after applying `map` has always the number of elements equal to the number of elements in the given list. As you are changing the same global dict, so returning it each time will send the reference of the same dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
print({i[0]:i[1] for i in zip(country,capital)})
```